# Bootstrap modal saves but doesn't change focus back to main app

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using two buttons to open the form:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="openBtn">Add Product/Event</button>    
<button ng-click="vm.showUpdate(product._id)" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Edit</button>
```

This is the modal form code:

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                     <h2><span ng-if="vm.addForm">Add Product/Event</span><span ng-if="vm.updateForm">Update Product/Event</span></h2>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal Body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form  ng-show="vm.addForm || vm.updateForm" name="vm.productForm" ng-submit="vm.saveProduct()" class="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="event">Product/Event:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="event" ng-model="vm.product.event" required/>
                            <div ng-show="vm.productForm.event.$dirty && vm.isSubmitted">Required field.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="division">Division:</label> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="division" ng-model="vm.product.division"/>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="level">Level:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="level" ng-model="vm.product.level"/>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="day">Day:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="day" ng-model="vm.product.day"/>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="group">Group:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="group" ng-model="vm.product.group" required/>
                            <div ng-show="vm.productForm.group.$dirty && vm.isSubmitted">Required field.</div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="numberofplayers"># Players:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.product.numberofplayers" name="numberofplayers"  min="0" max="4" integer />    
                            <div ng-show="vm.productForm.numberofplayers.$error.integer">The value is not a valid integer!</div>
                            <div ng-show="vm.productForm.numberofplayers.$error.min || vm.prodctForm.numberofplayers.$error.max">Players must be 0 - 4</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price">Price:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" ng-model="vm.product.price" integer required/>
                            <div ng-show="vm.productForm.price.$dirty && vm.isSubmitted">Required field.</div>
                            <div ng-show="vm.productForm.price.$error.integer">The price must be a valid integer!</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="description" ng-model="vm.product.description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="abbr">Export Abbr:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="abbr" ng-model="vm.product.abbr" required/>
                            <div ng-show="vm.productForm.abbr.$dirty && vm.isSubmitted">Required field.</div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="vm.saveProduct()"><span ng-if="vm.addForm">Save New</span><span ng-if="vm.updateForm">Save Changes</span></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal Footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.hideForm()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click Save, it saves the changes and closes the modal but does not update the main screen or return focus there (it stays grayed out).

I've tried adding data-dismiss="modal" to the save button, but that just closes the form and doesn't make any changes to the data.  I also tried some different ways to refresh the page, but I can't seem to refresh the page AND bring focus back - only one or the other.

My controller code:

```
//display and populate update form
    vm.showUpdate = function(id) {
        vm.addForm = false;
        vm.updateForm = true;
        //find product by ID and return to the view
        productDataFactory.productDisplay(id).then(function(response) {
            vm.product = response.data;
            console.log('Set vm.product from showUpdate', id);
        });
        $( '#myModal' ).modal('show');
    };

//save new or updated product, close modal, refresh the view    
vm.saveProduct = function() {
            console.log('Product/event form saved.');
            var postData =  {
                event: vm.product.event,
                description: vm.product.description,
            };
            if(vm.productForm.$valid) {
                //save new
                if(vm.addForm) {
                    productDataFactory.postProduct(postData).then(function(response){
                        if (response.status === 201) {
                            console.log(focused);
                            $( '#myModal' ).modal( 'hide' );
                            $( focused ).focus(); // returns focus to last active element
                            $route.reload();
                        }
                    }).catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });    
                //update existing 
                } else if (vm.updateForm) {
                    console.log('Updating ', vm.product._id);
                    productDataFactory.productUpdate(vm.product._id, postData).then(function(response){
                        if(response.status === 204) {
                            $( '#myModal' ).modal( 'hide' );
                            $('#product-main').element('show');
                            $route.reload();
                        }
                    }).catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
            //show errors
            } else {
                console.log('Invalid product form');
                vm.isSubmitted = true;
            }
        };
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get this to work, and I know a lot of other people are looking at it as well, so here is how I did it.  Thank you to glass duo for leading me in the right direction:

First, I used two different buttons to open the form:

```
<button ng-click="vm.openForm()" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Edit</button>
<button ng-click="vm.openForm(product._id)" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Edit</button>
```

I cleaned up the code in my controller, and used hidden.bs.modal to run the code to reload the page after the save:

```
vm.isSubmitted = false;
vm.formMode;

//set form mode to add or edit, display product info, if any, and show modal
    vm.openForm = function(id = null) {
        if(id) {
            //find product info
            vm.formMode = 'update';
            productDataFactory.productDisplay(id).then(function(response) {
            vm.product = response.data;
            console.log('Set vm.product from showUpdate', id);
            });
        } else if(id == null) {
            //populate blank form
            vm.formMode = 'add';
            vm.product = {};
            console.log('Generate blank form');
        }
        //display modal form
        $("#myModal").modal({backdrop: true});
    };

    vm.closeForm = function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
       $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            vm.formMode = null; //reset form mode
            $route.reload();
    });

    };

    vm.saveProduct = function() {
        console.log('Product/event form save button pressed.');
        var postData =  {
            event: vm.product.event,
            division: vm.product.division,
            level: vm.product.level,
            day: vm.product.day,
            group: vm.product.group,
            numberofplayers: parseInt(vm.product.numberofplayers, 10),
            price: parseInt(vm.product.price, 10),
            description: vm.product.description,
            abbr: vm.product.abbr
        };
        if(vm.productForm.$valid) {
            //save new
            if(vm.formMode === 'add') {
                productDataFactory.postProduct(postData).then(function(response){
                    if (response.status === 201) {
                        console.log('Saved product successfully');
                    }
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });    
            //update existing
            } else if (vm.formMode === 'update') {
                console.log('Updating ', vm.product._id);
                productDataFactory.productUpdate(vm.product._id, postData).then(function(response){
                    if(response.status == 204) {
                        console.log('Updated product successfully');
                    }
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
            //close form & refresh page
            vm.closeForm();
        //show errors
        } else { 
            console.log('Invalid product form');
            vm.isSubmitted = true;
        }
    };
```

Finally, I set the save and cancel buttons to run the appropriate code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="vm.saveProduct()">Save</button>
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.closeForm()">Cancel</button>
```

If you have the form submitting to saveProduct() along with these buttons, you'll save the model twice, so pick one or the other.

It should be noted that while I'm using angularjs, I used the regular bootstrap modal instead of angular-ui-bootstrap's modal.  Without using hidden-bs-modal, which allows you to run code AFTER the modal has closed, it just doesn't work refreshing the view with the updated code AND restoring active focus to the main view.

Comment: Glad I was at least able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm just going to assume you have a button to open your modal.  Perhaps your button looks something like this:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>`

What I suggest is that you not use the `target="#myModal"` and instead set up your button so that a function checks for it's click and then remembers current focus (so you can go back to it later) and then opens the modal.

So create a button like this, and I'm giving it the id `openBtn`.

`<button class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn">Open Modal</button>`

Then you could have some javascript that goes something like this:

```
var focused; // a variable to remember focus

$( '#openBtn' ).click(function () {
    focused = Document.activeElement; // remembers what element was active before modal opens
    $( '#myModal' ).modal( 'show' );
    // you could also manually set the focus to an element inside the modal if you wish, such as your h2 tag
});
```

And then for your `vm.addForm` and `vm.cancelForm` you can add the following code to close the modal and return focus to last active element.  So something like this in `vm.addForm` and `vm.cancelForm`:

```
$( '#myModal' ).modal( 'hide' );
$( focused ).focus(); // returns focus to last active element
```

As a note, with my code above, the only way to trigger the modal to open is by clicking on that button `openBtn`, therefore, the active element remembered in `focused` will always be `openBtn`.  However, if you had multiple buttons that could open the modal or you had a key command to open the modal (you can set up key commands using something like the [Mousetrap js library](https://craig.is/killing/mice) then it would be helpful to remember whatever was the last element rather than setting a default element to return focus to after the modal closes.

Comment: Yes, you are correct!  I actually had two buttons in the code above that.  One to add a new product and one to edit (from a list of products in a table, passing the id into a function).
`<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="openBtn">Add Product/Event</button>
<button ng-click="vm.showUpdate(product._id)" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Edit</button>`

It saves the changes and shows in the main window, but the main window still grayed out.  I am passing the hide modal and focus on last active element code in after the data saves.  I also tried adding $route.reload(); after that.

Comment: I updated my original post to reflect changes you recommended, but I'm still having issues getting the app to refresh the main view AND return focus to it.  I shared more code, in hopes that it helps.